# How to hide the pairing dialog box to programmatically pair a BLE device on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was trying to pair a BLE device programmatically from my android app.So at first I register a BroadcastReceiver for PAIRING_REQUEST.When device.createBond() is called ,the BroadcastReciever is triggered. When the   BroadcastReciever is triggered, I set the passkey by using setpin(). But the problem is  pairing request dialog box appeared sometimes and sometimes without appearing pairing box pairing is done automatically . I want that it will never show any dialog box but it should be paired with the passkey  programmatically.

Any solution of it ?

Or is there any way to fulfill my expectation? 
Thanks in advance.

**Registered broadCasterReciever during application launching**

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    intentFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
    appContext.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver,intentFilter);
```

**Implementation of broadcastReciever.**

```
    private  String BLE_PIN= "000012";
    private BroadcastReceiver broadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action))
                {
                    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    bluetoothDevice.setPin(BLE_PIN.getBytes());
                    Log.e("TAG","Auto-entering pin: " + BLE_PIN);

                }
           }
      };
```

And I called **device.createBond()** after discovering the device.

Comment: That's not possible, hiding the system dialogue box of Bluetooth pairing.

Comment: You can use Just Works pairing to get rid of the dialog if you can change the peripheral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling `abortBroadcast();` after `setPin()` solved the problem for me.

Comment: You are the best!